# Vector analysis proof

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

$$\vec{v}=3\vec{i}+4\vec{j}$$

If i and j are unit vectors, and there are 120 degrees between i and j, find the magnitude of v.

Now, if you choose numbers and do the problem you get an answer of about 4.098

But how to do this analytically? Could you take dot products of both sides? I haven't been able to solve this problem even after thinking about it quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a dot product. In general, the dot product of two vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ satisfies

$$ \vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} = \vert \vec x \vert \vert \vec y \vert \cos(\theta)$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors. (In fact, this is often the definition of the angle between two lines in a general space).

Here, you have both the magnitudes and the angle between the two vectors.

Comment: No but you don't know the angle between anything on the left of the equation, that's why it's hard.

Comment: You'd have to derive an expression for the angle between v and i which is hard.

Comment: The dot product is linear. That one angle is the only angle you need.

Comment: um, but are you dotting both sides by i? what exactly are you proposing?

Comment: Look at v dotted with v. Expand linearly.

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude is $\sqrt{v\cdot v}$, hence you have $ \sqrt{9 i\cdot i + 24 j\cdot i + 16 j\cdot j}$ that leads to $ \sqrt{ 9 + 16 +24 \cos(120)}=\sqrt{ 25+24(-0.5)}$.